# Match one by one or match all in one regex line (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

I have a task that parses an email body content and extract a couple of words inside it.
It's not really that important how I extract those words, but Im curious which of the 2 options below is faster or suggested.

```
1. $email =~ /(date) (time) (some other pattern)/;
   my $date = $1;
   my $time = $2;
   my $other_pattern = $3;

2. $email =~ /(date)/;
   my $date = $1;
   $email =~ /(time)/;
   my $time = $1
   $email =~ /(some other pattern)/;
   my $other_pattern = $1;
```

Number 1 wherein match all in one regex line or number 2 where I match one by one? and why.

Comment: Generally, regex operations will be faster if they're split up like in your second example. This is because the regex engine won't have to backtrack as it matches the various groups. However, many people find the single line approach with `$1` `$2` `$3` grouping to be easier to read and understand. You also might be able to leverage strict ordering rules in your input to make a more reliable and concise pattern (for example, if the date is always at the beginning of the string, you can help identify it with `^`).

Comment: It depends upon the actual form of the text being matched. If it is done as #2 there is the possibility that date/time/body are matched in the wrong parts. If looking for a good question to start intelligent discussion, this really isn't it. This could turn into an _out_of_order_ match question but even that should be done with a single regex.

Comment: Please add the actual patterns to help with run time comparison estimates.

Answer (score 1):

The first method, using the three patterns in one regex, will probably be preferred in most cases. This is because it is more familiar and thus easier to maintain. The date and time especially seem to naturally go into one regex.
Remember to add the `x` flag for readability.
Consider using   `Regexp::Common::time`: https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::time .
Capture directly into the variables instead of `$1` etc for speed and readability:

```
my ($date, $time, $other) = $email =~ m{...}x;
```